# VB.net (desktop) context menu assigned to multiple controls owner problem

Tags: vb.net, controls, contextmenu

I have two different grid controls on the same form. They share the same context menu. I am having trouble determining which control is the owner when I select the context menu item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SourceControl property on the ContextMenuStrip class will show the last control that caused that menu strip to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler for the MenuItem's Click event will have a Sender parameter. This object should be the control that had the focus when the context menu was displayed.

Comment: Sorry but all that will give you is a reference to the actual menu item that was clicked, not the control that was right clicked to fire the context menu.