# How do you get the control that was clicked to open a ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, event-handling, contextmenustrip

I'm using a `ContextMenuStrip` for multiple controls and I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the control that was actually clicked on to open the Context Menu.  The sender just gives the `ToolStripMenuItem` reference, which has an Owner property that references the `ContextMenuStrip`, but I cannot figure out how to tell which control the click came from.  There must be a simple way to check this, right?  I'm checking it in the `ToolStripMenuItem`'s click event.

```
Friend WithEvents mnuWebCopy As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
...
Private Sub mnuWebCopy_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuWebCopy.Click
```

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244002/vb-net-desktop-context-menu-assigned-to-multiple-controls-owner-problem) about this, but that mentions using a `SourceControl` property which I do not see on here.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, VB.Net winforms.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Private Sub mnuWebCopy_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuWebCopy.Click

Dim myItem As ToolStripMenuItem = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim cms As ContextMenuStrip = CType(myItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)

MessageBox.Show(cms.SourceControl.Name)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was missing.

Answer (score 6):

Your sender is a ToolStripMenuItem -- cast it.
Its owner is a ContextMenuStrip -- get it.

SourceControl is a property on the ContextMenuStrip and references the last control from which the ContextMenuStrip was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub kdgToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles kdgToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim sms = (sender.GetCurrentParent()).SourceControl.name
    MsgBox(sms)
End Sub
```

'///Faster

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmsRightClick_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles cmsRightClick.MouseClick
    Dim s As String = CType(sender, ContextMenuStrip).GetItemAt(CType(sender, ContextMenuStrip).DisplayRectangle.X, _
     CType(sender, ContextMenuStrip).DisplayRectangle.Y + e.Y).Text.Trim()


    MsgBox(s)
    Select Case s 
        Case Is = "Select Summary Total"
            Dim x = 0
        Case Is = "Select Collections"
            Dim x = 1
        Case Is = "UnSelect"
            Dim x = 2
        Case Is = "Reconcile"
            Dim x = 3
        Case Is = "Undo Reconciliation"
            Dim x = 4
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

On VB.NET 2013 this work so fine:

```
Dim cms As ContextMenuStrip = CType(sender, ContextMenuStrip)
MessageBox.Show(cms.SourceControl.Name)
```